# Data is not sent from a form. MODX revolution

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

CMF MODX revolution

There is a template with a form

```
<form action="http://localhost/index.php?id=3" method="post">
        <input type="name" name="name">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Все товары" name="search_bar">
        <input type="submit" value="">
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</form>
```

which call a snippet which contains debugging line:

```
echo '|||||||||||| ', $_POST['search_bar'];
```

The problem.
If I put a value into search bar - echo will not show anything. But if I save the template
before I putt the value into the search bar and click submit button, then echo display right value from the search bar

Suppose the problem is in caching. But I cleaned it and it is cancelled everywhere (at least I think so, exploring administrator panel).

Comment: As i have tested all code is okay. Exactly what issue are you facing?

Comment: You might be calling the code cached. Sure your snippet is called with the `!`-flag?

Comment: Thank you,  OptimusCrime, now it works

Answer (score 0):

For Snippets that depend on user input (like a search query) you will want to call them uncached: `[[!mySnippet]]`

However if you want to gain a bit of performance you can wrap the Snippet call with Jason Coward's [getCache](http://modx.com/extras/package/getCache), and by default it caches to a unique cache key based on the $_GET parameters. In other words, each search query would get its own cache object. This helps when there are repeat searches for the same string.